# Why is the compiler showing undefined control sequence?

Tags: compilation-error

Why is the compiler showing undefined control sequence for the below code: Note that I have already given the preamble of `\usepackage{amsmath}`

> A Hoheisel Algebra is a core structure with $R=\mathbb{C}\ \ S=\mathbb{R}$, $A$ a commutative algebra, $B$ finite with $\beta_{iiH0}\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}\forall i\in I$.

Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, possibly starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. The exact error message would be helpful too: the console output has a line break at the undefined sequence.

Comment: Did you load `amssymb` (or `amsfonts`)? Otherwise no `\mathbb`...

Comment: @campa thanks, loaded the package and the error is gone?